# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

From MainActivity, I am instantiating a simple fragment like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new RentFragment();
```

And the RentFragment.java is like this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class RentFragment extends Fragment {

    public RentFragment(){} 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rent, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

The fragment_rent.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Rent"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the error log is like this:

```
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at com.example.devicerentalsystem.RentFragment.onCreateView(RentFragment.java:15)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at  android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     ... 19 more
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.devicerentalsystem-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.devicerentalsystem-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
 09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
09-16 13:32:32.759: E/AndroidRuntime(9131):     ... 22 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your `Maninactivity` code

Comment: change `com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment` to your won package and Fragment name

Comment: change it to com.example.RentFragment

Comment: please put your fragment calling code. then only we can tell why this error occurs. May be the error due to the inflation of fragment into the view which contains another fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what the problem was. A fragment can not hold another fragment. So I added a framelayout in xml and used fragment manager to replace that with my own fragment.

Thanks everybody for the help.

xml:

```
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="scanAgain"
        android:text="Re-Scan" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

change in java:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sample, (Fragment)headlineFrag).commit();
```